# Trying to open the dialog to specify project path in netbeans takes literally 2 minutes

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-8

What i mean is i'm trying to open a project and the window to specify the path comes up that takes 2 minutes to open. If i click desktop it takes another 2 minutes to open desktop contents. What is going on i'm going insane. That never happened before.
I tried using another java app and it does the same thing every time i have to choose the file.

Netbeans displays this message that i have found no fix yet: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wm43k.jpg

Comment: Have you tried upgrading jdk as it says in the error

Comment: @Lazycoder_007 i have the latest version. java version "1.8.0_251"